# why i cant create a hole with bool tool addon

Tags: modifiers, add-on

I have array of 10 sphere. With the array applied. I removed all the doubles and checked the scale of both the mesh. I tried to make a hole with the *Bool Tool* addon. Selecting the sphere and the mesh pressing ctrl + -(minus) key. 2 Sphere disappear and it did not cut the hole. It looks like they joined the mesh. Thanks

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Geometry is too much complex.
Change **Overlap Threshold** in *Boolean Modifier* to zero.

[image]